# Understanding a proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem using degree of map

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation

The following is to be proven: Every map $f:D^n\to D^n$ has a fixed point.

I found the following solution online:

Let $g:S^n\to S^n$ be a map that sends both hemispheres to southern hemispheres $\color{red}{\text{via $f$}}$. Then $g$ is not surjective hence has degree $0$. It follows that $g$ has a fixed point. That fixed point must lie on southern hemisphere and $\color{red}{\text{ must be a fixed point of $f$ also.}}$

I don't understand the red colored parts. Can anyone please explain these to me? Thanks.

Comment: It would help to add the source, if you have it - "what does [unknown source] mean when it says X" is not something that generally be answered by people who lack even the context that you have.  Does this thread (about a problem in a version of Hatcher) from "Ask a Topologist" help? http://at.yorku.ca/b/ask-an-algebraic-topologist/2020/1194.htm

Comment: I would guess that there is a map $\phi :D^n \to \mathbb S^n$ given by $\phi (x) = (x, \sqrt{1-|x|^2})$. Then given $f$, $g$ is given by $g(x) = \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1} (x)$ if $x_{n+1} \ge 0$, and $g(x', x_{n+1}) =  g(x', -x_{n+1})$ when $x_{n+1}<0$.

Comment: The solution being referred to in the post is solution 1) [here](https://pages.uoregon.edu/njp/635hw4solutions.pdf).

Comment: @ArcticChar Thanks a lot. I think this fits. So with this since deg g=0, we have $f(\phi^{-1}(x))= \phi^{-1}(x)$ for some $x$.

Comment: @leslietownes: I added the link now.

Comment: You changed a word. The pdf says "**the** map $g$", not "a map $g$". This means $g$ refers to a specific map defined from $f$. I expect you will find that map explicitly defined somewhere in Hatcher, chapter 2.2. (almost certainly the map Arctic Char mentions, or a trivial variant).

Comment: @Koro You should now write an answer to your own question.

Comment: @PaulFrost done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiling the ideas suggested in the comments, here is my solution:

Define $\phi: S^n\to D^n$ as $\phi(x_0,x_1,...,x_n)=(x_0,x_1,...,x_{n-1})$.

Define $\psi: D^n\to (S^n)^+$ as $\psi(y_1,y_2,...,y_n)= \left(y_1,y_2,...,y_n, \sqrt{1-\sum_{i=1}^n|y_i|^2}\right)$. Here, $(S^n)^+$ denotes the northern hemisphere with boundary.

Now consider the composition $\psi f \phi: S^n\to S^n$. This is not an onto map as the southern pole in $S^n$ has no preimage. So  deg $(\psi f\phi)=0$.

It follows that $\psi f\phi$ has a fixed point $p\in S^n$ (in the northern hemisphere i.e., $p\in (S^n)^+$). $\psi f\phi (p)=p$.

$\psi$ is a bijection.  So we have $f(\phi(p))= \psi^{-1}(p)$.

Now, note that $\psi^{-1}(p)= \phi(p)=q,$ say.

It follows that $f(q)=q.$