# Prove the Brouwer fixed point theorem for maps $f : D^n \to D^n$ by applying degree theory to the map $S^n \to S^n$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Prove the Brouwer fixed point theorem for maps $f : D^n \to D^n$ by applying degree theory to the map $S^n \to S^n$ that sends both the northern and southern hemispheres of $S^n$ to the southern hemisphere via $f$.

I am trying to understand this via $f$ here, but I have some issues with it. If $N$ is the northern hemisphere and $S$ is the southern, then we have that $$g(N) =S \text{ and } g(S)=S.$$

Now do we get a map $$S^n \to D^n \xrightarrow{f} D^n \to S^n$$ where the map $S^n \to S^n$ is $g$? I think since $g$ is not surjective it has degree $0$, but this is where my understanding stops.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4694616/understanding-a-proof-of-brouwers-fixed-point-theorem-using-degree-of-map

Comment: In the comments to the above link, you'll see how g is created using f.

Comment: So they have that for the map $D^n \to S^n$ given by $\phi (x) = (x, \sqrt{1-|x|^2})$ the map $g$ takes the form $$g = \phi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$$ and $$\deg(g)= \deg(\phi)\deg(f)\deg(\phi^{-1}) = 0.$$ This still doesn't imply that $\deg(f) = 0$ since $\deg(\phi)$ or $\deg(\phi^{-1})$ could be zero? @Koro

Comment: You don't have to worry about deg f. If deg g=0, then g has a fixed point (by (g) at page no. 134 of Hatcher's). Call it p.  g(p)=p= $\phi (f(\phi^{-1}(p)))\implies \color{blue}{\phi^{-1}(p)}= f(\color{blue}{\phi^{-1}(p)}).$

Comment: The proposition on Hatcher's book says that a map $f : S^n \to S^n$ that has no fixed point has degree $(-1)^{n+1}$, but not that a map with degree zero would always have a fixed point? @Koro

Comment: Suppose on the contrary that g has no fixed points, then deg g = $(-1)^{n+1}$. But this contradicts the fact that deg g=0.

Comment: I have written an answer here (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4702405/266435), you might wanna take a look at it. :-)